# Can't find Chromecast serial number to register my device

Tags: google-cast

I'm trying to register my chromecast device for development [on the console](https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview) following this guide:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration
 But it seems like its outdated, because when I follow the instructions its " cast this tab" instead of cast.google.com or whatever and the serial number never shows up on the screen.

I also followed the instructions on [this page](https://support.google.com/store/answer/3333000?hl=en-CA) and checked my box/device,
but there was no number on the box and number on the device was extremely faint and didn't work.

So how do I obtain the serial number for my device?

If it's relevant, my firmware version is 38401 and my country code is US (but I'm in Canada)

Comment: Try contacting the Google Cast Developer [Help Center](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us) for assistance.

Comment: If I could give you a million up's for this I would. I have been looking for a way to do that since I bought my new tv that has a chromecast device inside it.

Comment: General heads up: the Developer Console will let you register incorrect serial numbers. I misread mine and it took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 58):

Its been a while since you asked this but I'm gonna answer this for rest of the folks out there.

There are two ways to get the Serial Number:

**First:** (Easy way)

See back of your device.

For the new model:

[image: New Chromecast]

For the older Model:

[image]

.

.

.

**Second: Use Google Cast developer tool to get the Serial Number:**

This is the same way that Google Developer website suggest; however, it didn't work for me the first time. But after I added the serial number from back of the device, I could see this working.

Here are the steps:
A) Login to Google Chromecast developer console at https://cast.google.com/publish

B) Click on "ADD NEW DEVICE" red sign. (I assume u already registered for Cast development.)

[image]

C) The following window should opens up.

[image]

**Pay attention:**
If you can see the 'sound' icon next to the question mark and "Serial Number", it means u'll be able to move forward in the process. This icon was not visible to me the first time I tried to get the serial number.

After you click on it, u'll be able to see "Cast cast.google.com to..."

[image]

D) You click on the dropdown menu, u click on the first line and once it checked, u go back and then u cast your device. (In my case I clicked on "Sam's Chromecast"

[image]

[image]

After you do this, a giant Serial Number would appear on your chromecast screen.
Please comment if I can make things more clear for you.

Comment: It was very useful! Especially androidTV part. Thank you

Comment: wow this answer should be ticked as correct one

Answer (score 6):

There is now another even easier method to get your Chromecast serial number, but because most of the documentation is really old it's just not mentioned anywhere.

When you are adding a device on the [Google Cast SDK Developer Console](https://cast.google.com/publish)

You should see this screen pop:
[image]

If you click the speaker icon next to "Serial Number" your Chromecast's serial number will be displayed on whatever screen it is connected to.

Edit: As @kubi noted in the comments it appears that you can only see this button on chrome so make sure you are not using firefox.

Comment: Very helpful since the S/N on my 2nd gen Chromecast is barely legible, even with a magnifying glass. Just keep in mind to use Google Chrome to use the link; there was no speaker icon on Firefox for me.

Comment: Same problem xD. I struggled with Firefox until I found this.