# Android TV Chromecast Serial Number

Tags: android, device, chromecast, android-tv

I am trying to add Chromecast from Android TV to cast develop devices list, but...

While trying to fetch device serial, on TV is shown "0123456789ABCDEF". I tried to add that to list, but then I get message that something went wrong (as expected).

I also tried to add Android TV serial number as serial number to devices list and then tried to start cast from development app, but, app doesn't see Android TV.

How to get correct Chromecast device serial number? Thanks!

Android TV model is Philips 43PUS6501/12

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, finally I get Serial number from sticker at back of the device, after adding it to developer console you need to wait some time

Comment: Did you enter TV serial or is there another one?

Answer (score 1):

Based from [Google Cast - Devices](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#RegisterDevice), you may obtain the serial number as follows:

> 1. Click the Cast button (as if you were casting this page). The extension displays **Cast: cast.google.com to...** and lists the devices available.
> 2. From the drop-down menu, select the device for which you want to obtain the serial number.
>
>    For Chromecast and Android TV devices, the serial number displays on the TV screen and plays aloud on the TV speakers.
>
>    For Cast for audio devices, the serial number plays aloud on the Cast for audio device speakers.
>
> For an Android TV device you can also get the serial number on Android TV: from the **Settings** menu, select **About** and scroll down to see the **Serial Number**.

Lastly, please note that when registering your Google Cast device, wait fifteen minutes after you have entered the serial number before continuing. Once registration is complete, the Status for the device will read "Ready for Testing."

Comment: Yes, I tried that what you are quoting here and I get "0123456789ABCDEF" as serial number.

On Android TV: Settings - About - and there is no serial number displayed.

Comment: I have the same issue with Philips 65PUS7120/12. But it shows "UNKNOWN" word instead of "0123456789ABCDEF".

Comment: I solved this by take a look behind the TV and take the serial number from the ticket on the back of the TV.

Comment: I was using an external shield device and found the option in `settings>status>serialnumber`

Answer (score 0):

None of the tips here worked for my Android TV, here's how I solved it (take a look at the second part of the answer): [Can't find Chromecast serial number to register my device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062941/cant-find-chromecast-serial-number-to-register-my-device)

Comment: It's best if you could *quote* something from that answer.